# How to avoid duplicates in GAE datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Let's say here is the database structure:

```
class News(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()

class NewsRating(db.Model):
    user = db.IntegerProperty()
    rating = db.IntegerProperty()
    news = db.ReferenceProperty(News)
```

Each user can leave only one rating for each News. The following code doesn't care about duplicates:

```
rating = NewsRating()
rating.user = 123456
rating.rating = 1
rating.news = News.get_by_key_name('news-unique-key')
rating.put()
```

How should I modify that that it will allow to have only one record for each `rating.user` and `rating.news` combination? If such rating already exists, then it should be updated with new value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use key names and (possibly) parent entities to keep track. For instance, supposing you have a `UserInfo` kind, you could do it like this:

```
class NewsRating(db.Model):
  # No explicit user reference, since it's the parent entity
  rating = db.IntegerProperty(required=True)
  news = db.ReferenceProperty(News) # We could get this from the key name, but this is more convenient

rating = NewsRating(parent=current_user, key_name=str(news.key().id()), news=news)
rating.put()
```

Attempting to add the same rating multiple times will simply overwrite the existing one, or you can use a datastore transaction to add it atomically.

Note that you should almost certainly keep a total of ratings against the `News` entity, rather than counting up ratings on each request, which will get less efficient as the number of ratings increases.

Comment: Nick, is it possible to have 2 records with the same `key_name`, but with different parents?